# Src attribute not loading image

Tags: html

So I accidently dragged my folder of images for my website and it just disappeared into the program not knowing what it has done... Now when I enter the pathway of the image. Visual Studio doesn't find the image. It USE to have a drop list when enter the pathway.. but it doesn't show at all. Help?

I tried deleting Visual Studio in hopes of going back to default settings. But It's still having the same issue